# Enviar caractere especial no corpo do Request via HttpRequest no Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, xml, api, http-request, nfe

Estou consumindo uma API (POST), via Delphi para envio do XML da NF-e. Estou usando o HttpRequest.

No corpo da requisição (body) devo passar o xml da seguinte forma:
xml=

Porém a razão social do emitente (xNome) contém o caractere especial "&". Ao enviar a informação para a API ele retorna um erro:

> XML de nota com sintaxe quebrada ou inválida: Premature end of data in tag xNome line 1

Pelo que entendi, a API está entendendo que esse & se refere a um novo parâmetro, quebrando a String do XML.

Como eu faço para enviar uma informação com esse caractere especial "&" de forma que a API não entenda como parâmetro e sim como texto/string do Xml?

Meu código está assim:

```
Request.Uri := BASE_URL + '?token='+ FToken;
Request.Method := 'POST';
Request.Headers.SetValue('Accept', 'application/xml');
Request.Headers.SetValue('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
Request.Headers.SetValue('Authorization', 'Basic '+EncodeString(Format('%s:%s', [FUsuario, FSenha])));
Request.SetContent(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Concat('xml=', FXML.Text)));
```

Comment: Tenta trocar o `&` por `&amp;` e vê se resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Você só precisa usar os caracteres de escape.

Caracter de escape é uma forma de você dizer que o caractere `&` é um caractere realmente e não apenas um parâmetro.

Se você coloca um caractere como `<` dentro de um elemento XML element, ele irá gerar um erro porque o parser o interpreta como o início de um novo elemento.

Para evitar isso, você deve substituir o caractere `<` por uma referência de entidade, assim:

Isso:

```
<mensagem>se saldo < 1000 então não tenho dinheiro</mensagem>
```

Vira isso:

```
<mensagem>se saldo &lt; 1000 então não tenho dinheiro</mensagem>
```

Há 5 referências de entidade pré-definidas na XML:

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```

Então quando for informar a razão social do emitente basta trocar o `&` por `&amp;`

Você pode ver um pouco mais sobre isso neste [link](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/xml-escaped-chars.html), neste [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents) e [neste outro também](http://hugoribeiro.com.br/Curso_HTML/xml/c15.htm).

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda mas não resolveu. Eu identifiquei o problema através do Postman. Pelo Postman o Xml é passado no body pelo tipo x-www-form-urlencoded (key=value).

Porém não encontro a opção no HttpRequest para passar dessa forma. O SetContent escreve diretamente no body/raw (aqui é inválido)

Comment: Beleza então... Você conhece o ACBr? É um componente open source que é bem utilizado para tratar de DFes, com ele você não precisa ficar montando o XML inteiro da nota na mão, fica a dica caso não conheça!

Comment: Sim conheço e utilizo Matheus. A API que me refiro não é para a emissão. É uma API de terceiro para armazenar/guardar o XML da NF-e.

Comment: felipearon, Pode fazer HTTPReq.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'; nao?

Answer (score 0):

### Não faça XML "na mão"

Isso aqui:

```
<tag>a&b</tag>
```

É um XML inválido. O `&` é um caracter especial. O a "letra" `&` precisa estar assim no XML:

```
<tag>a&amp;b</tag>
```

Percebe como as cores ficam diferentes, nos exemplos acima? Isso é justamente o colorir do site conseguindo (ou não) entender o XML como válido.

Isso significa que o `FXML.Text` está entregando/produzindo um XML inválido. Provavelmente porque ele está concatenando as tags na mão sem se preocupar com caracteres especiais. Péssima ideia.

**Não há nada que você possa mudar nesse código aí para corrigir esse problema.** O problema está em outro lugar.

A solução do seu problema é ver onde o XML desse `FXML.Text` é criado e nesse ponto usar uma biblioteca XML de verdade.

A solução *ruim* do seu problema é ir onde o XML do `FXML.Text` é criado e em todo lugar que concatena um texto, fazer antes replace na string de todos os caracteres especiais, conforme a resposta do [Matheus Ribeiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/370471/41731).